# How do I update Swift Dictionary values of mixed types, in particular Arrays

Tags: swift, dictionary, types

I have a dictionary of mixed types (string, NSImage, and an Array). When appending to the array, I get the error "Value of type 'Any??' has no member 'append'". I don't see how to cast "file_list" value as an Array so I can append values to it.

```
            var dataDict: [String:Any?] = [
                "data_id" : someString,
                "thumbnail" : nil,
                "file_list" : [],
            ]
            // do stuff... find files... whirrr wizzzz
            dataDict["thumbnail"] = NSImage(byReferencingFile: someFile)
            dataDict["file_list"].append( someFile ) <- ERROR: Value of type 'Any??' has no member 'append'
```

Comment: Why don't you use some struct like `struct DataDict {var dataId: String; var thumbname: NSImage?; var fileList: [String]}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You need to first get your key value, cast from `Any` to `[String]`, append the new value and then assign the modified array value to your key:

```
if var array = dataDict["file_list"] as? [String] {
    array.append(someFile)
    dataDict["file_list"] = array
}
```

or

```
if let array =  dataDict["file_list"] as? [String] {
    dataDict["file_list"] = array + [someFile]
}
```

Another option is to create a custom struct as suggested in comments by OOPer